# How to group by in MySQL while depending on value for calculation?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to perform a calculation in MySQL 5.7 and group by date and manufacturer_id. My goal is to find the result of this formula for each day and manufacturer.

The select statment for one manufacturer looks like this minimal example:

```
 SELECT
  mks.date,
  (
      SUM (
      CASE 
        WHEN p.MANUFACTURER_ID  = 18670  
        THEN (2 / mks.test)
       END 
      ) / SUM ((2 / mks.test))
  )  AS  'Example'
from search mks
INNER JOIN products p on mks.ARTICLE_ID = p.ARTICLE_ID
GROUP BY
   mks.date
```

It is based on table products (holding all product info) and table search (holding all search results per manufacturer.

Basically what it does is to calculate the percentage for each manufacturer within the result set.

Now this works for one, because I filter for this particular manufacturer within the case statement. But how do I generalize this with a group by date, maufacturer_id so I can get a percentage for each manufacturer in the result set (equaling to 100% in total)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your `2 / col` stuff, so I'll present a general solution.

```sql
SELECT a.date,
       b.manufacturer_id,
       ROUND(100.0 * SUM(a.value) / tot.grand_total, 1) percent
  FROM a
  JOIN b ON b.b_id = a.b_id
 CROSS JOIN ( SELECT SUM(a.value) grand_total 
                FROM a
                JOIN b ON b.b_id = a.b_id
            ) tot
 GROUP BY a.date, b.manufacturer_id
```

You use a subquery to get the grand total and then you CROSS JOIN it to your table so you can use it as a divisor.

If you want the result for just one `manufacturer_id` you can append `WHERE b.manufacturer_id = something` to that query.